# In Guava, how to create a Multiset with a single element and n occurrences

Tags: java, guava, multiset

I'd like to create an (immutable) Multiset in Guava that has a single entry `element` with occurrences `occurrences`, both of which are not known at compile time.

What I've come up with is this:

```
ImmutableMultiset.<X>builder().addCopies(element, occurrences).build()
```

I guess I was looking for a method like this:

```
public static ImmutableMultiset<X> ImmutableMultiset.nOccurrencesOf(
X element, int occurrences){}
```

or:

```
public static ImmutableMultiset<X> Multisets.singletonMultiset(
X element, int occurrences){}
```

Is there any method I have overlooked that makes the above code shorter?

Comment: What is wrong with what you found? Guava will not tend to give a different signature for each possible use case when a simple solution already exists. This seems to be the case with using the builder.

Comment: @JohnB there are many different overloaded methods in ImmutableMultiset, and I find it strange that this one is missing

Comment: I think since they put it in the builder, they didn't see a need to put it in the class directly. Notice that the only `add` method in the class is just there to satisfy the interface and throws an exception.

Comment: The main problem I have is that in my version, generic type information is lost, and I have to parameterize the builder() call. A dedicated method could change that.

Comment: Although it would be nice, I don't see the guava team making this change. The added methods would be of very limited value since they would create an immutable set into which no additional elements could be added. They would make the case that it is pretty rare to have a scenario where the ONLY thing you want in a set is 5 instances of X. The current builder allows for this with the flexibility that would be needed in general. The generic specification is a small price to pay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guava contributor here.

Stick with the builder.  It already addresses the problem quite simply, and in a single line; it's probably not a common enough case to require its own special method.

Comment: That's what I feared. So there's a `.singletonMultiset(
X element, int occurrences)` in my own code base now. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-line solution that doesn't use a builder.

```
ImmutableMultiset<X> multiset = 
  ImmutableMultiset.copyOf(Collections.nCopies(occurrences, element));
```

However, this has one drawback: its run time scales with the number of occurrences. For better performance, use one of the other methods.

Comment: Nice. It's just as bulky as the builder version (with the exception that it doesn't require me to pass generic parameters), so I'll still stick with my factory method approach, but this is definitely a valid answer to make the picture more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option but it doesn't seem as good as the builder option you presented:

```
Multiset<X> set = HashMultiset.create();
set.add(element, occurrences);
ImmutableMultiset<X> immutableSet = ImmutableMultiset.copyOf(set);
```

Comment: That's worse, mine's a one-liner.